# Hackerrank, Utopian Tree in Haskell

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell

> ### [Problem statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/utopian-tree)
>
> The Utopian tree goes through 2 cycles of growth every year. The first
>   growth cycle occurs during the monsoon, when it doubles in height. The
>   second growth cycle occurs during the summer, when its height
>   increases by 1 meter.  Now, a new Utopian tree sapling is planted at
>   the onset of the monsoon. Its height is 1 meter. Can you find the
>   height of the tree after \$N\$ growth cycles?
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains an integer, \$T\$, the number of test cases. 
>   \$T\$ lines follow. Each line contains an integer, \$N\$, that denotes
>   the number of cycles for that test case.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> ```
> 1 <= T <= 10 
> 0 <= N <= 60
> ```
>
> **Sample Input: #01:**
>
> ```
> 2
> 3
> 4
> ```
>
> **Sample Output: #01:**
>
> ```
> 6
> 7
> ```
>
> **Explanation: #01:**
>
> There are 2 testcases.
>
> *N = 3:*
>   * the height of the tree at the end of the 1st cycle = 2 
>   * the height of the tree at the end of the 2nd cycle = 3 
>   * the height of the tree at the end of the 3rd cycle = 6
>
> *N = 4:*
>
> - the height of the tree at the end of the 4th cycle = 7

**This is my accepted solution:**

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad(mapM_)

main = do
    let base_height = 1
    n_test_cases <- readLn
    test_cases <- getList n_test_cases
    mapM_ (\i -> putStrLn $ show $ utopianTreeHeight base_height 
        (test_cases !! i)) [0..n_test_cases - 1]

getList :: Int -> IO [Int]
getList n = 
    if n == 0
        then return []
    else
        do
            x <- readLn
            xs <- getList (n - 1)
            return (x:xs)

utopianTreeHeight :: Int -> Int -> Int
utopianTreeHeight present_height 0 = present_height
utopianTreeHeight present_height cycles = 
    if odd cycles
        then 2 * (utopianTreeHeight present_height (cycles - 1))
    else
        1 + (utopianTreeHeight present_height (cycles - 1))
```

So, does this solution show good Haskell style? What could be improved? I have doubts especially regarding the way I deal with the IO (which was not provided by Hackerrank), as it was the first time I read about and applied  the Haskell way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For the main function

1 : you can replace `getList` with `replicateM`

2 : replace `putStrLn $ show` with `print`

3 : you can pass `test_cases` directly to `mapM_`

4 : you also don't need to import `mapM_`

5 : you should use camelCase for names instead of snake_case

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

main = do
  numberOfTests <- readLn
  testCases <- replicateM numberOfTests readLn
  mapM_ (print . utopian) testCases
```

Answer (score 3):

Your solution lacks the use of higher-order functions that are an essential part of Haskell style. Instead of writing explicitly recursive functions that plumb state around (like an impoverished for-loop) seek out, create, and use constructs that have semantic meaning to your problem.

Starting from the small, the problem defines a growth cycle as a either doubling a tree's height, or increasing it by one. We can encode all of that information in Haskell.

```
type Height = Integer
type Cycle = Height -> Height

monsoon :: Cycle
monsoon = (* 2)

summer :: Cycle
summer = (+ 1)
```

Next, we know that the cycles begin with a monsoon and thereafter proceed regularly indefinitely into the future.

```
timeline :: [Cycle]
timeline = cycle [monsoon, summer]
```

`cycle` is a function from the Haskell `Prelude` module which turns a finite list into an infinite list by infinitely repeating it. Now we can take a finite sequence from the front of the list to determine all of the cycles the tree will experience over a given span of time.

```
-- code fragment
take n timeline :: [Cycle] -- n cycles from planting
```

Now given the original height of the tree and the cycles it will experience over a given span of time, we can find the resulting height of the tree.

```
utopian :: Int -> Height
utopian n = foldl (flip ($)) 1 $ take n timeline
```

We fold over the finite timeline from the left, applying each growth function to the accumulator (starting with the height of the tree at year 0).

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at the first few values for even \$N\$:

```
*Main> [ utopianTreeHeight 1 n | n <- [0, 2 .. 20] ]
[1,3,7,15,31,63,127,255,511,1023,2047]
```

They're all one less than a power of two:

```
*Main> [ 1 + utopianTreeHeight 1 n | n <- [0, 2 .. 20] ]
[2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048]
```

What about for odd values of \$N\$?

```
*Main> [ utopianTreeHeight 1 n | n <- [1, 3 .. 20] ]
[2,6,14,30,62,126,254,510,1022,2046]
```

They're all two less than a power of two:

```
*Main> [ 2 + utopianTreeHeight 1 n | n <- [1, 3 .. 20] ]
[4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048]
```

This is a hint that we can find a closed-form formula for the \$N\$th term:

```
height :: Int -> Int
height n | even n    = (2 ^ x) - 1
         | otherwise = (2 ^ x) - 2
         where x = (n + 1) `div` 2 + 1
```